# Clipping Gradient with stochastic gradient descent

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gradient, recurrent-neural-network, clipping

I'm training a recurrent neural network, but I want to apply the clipping gradient. I'm using sgd. Can I use the clipping gradient to the sum of the gradients computed for a minibatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipping the sum of the gradients has no effect. You should instead clip each gradient individually.

Here is a quick code snippet for gradient clipping in Tensorflow:

```
max = 20
grads = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, max)  # gradient clipping
grads_and_vars = list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables()))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```